# How can I export my system preferences?

Tags: settings, system-settings, macos, setup

Is there a way for me to export my system preferences on my Mac for quick install on another machine?

An example of what I am trying to accomplish is, when I start a new job, I would like to import my settings and have my system preference work without having to manually configure all of my custom settings.

I am most interested in exporting settings for :

- Trackpad / Mouse
- Keyboard
- Dock
- dashboard (I like to disable it)

Comment: What system preference exactly are you trying to export? It is needed so I can provide the code necessary for a quick install

Comment: I will be updating my answer adding more due to the fact that I don't have time ;) For now, I put the mouse/trackpad

Comment: Ok I finished the full answer. I am at my iPad though. So make sure to dheck if for example `com.apple.preference.mouse` is correct by doing the ls command. Once you have done the script, you can save it as application and double click anywhere and it will install.

Comment: Changed the answer fully, because it was all wrong, and all the preferences are withouth the ....preference.... in the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated my answer because all of it was wrong:

---

You will want to use an applescript for your preference setups. Here is the code for some of them and screenshots of the actual plist so you get an idea of the options possible. IF this does not apply straight away, you might need to restart the computer. **Don't forget to save applescript as an Application. NOT script**

## Trackpad/Mouse

In here, it varies. It is either `com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse` for mouse, `com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse` for bluetooth mouse, and `com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad` for trackpad

```
tell application "Terminal"
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.AppleHIDMouse Button2 1"
end tell
```

The example above changes right click to be left click as well

## Keyboard

Unfortunately, I could not find a preference for keyboard. I will keep on searching though.

## Dock

```
tell application "Terminal"
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dock autohide YES"
end tell
```

This was just an example. Switch autohide with whatever option and YES with value or boolean. Booleans are YES and NO (unlike in scripts "true" "false") I put a picture on the end so you can see all the possible options for all the options.

## Disable Dashboard

I also could not find how to. Though it is presumably in `com.apple.spaces`

Dock options:
[image]

Mouse:
[image]

Bluetooth Mouse
[image]

Comment: The `keyboard` preferences are the most important ones: sad to see not possible

Answer (score 8):

I wrote some scripts to backup and restore Mac preferences. It does both System and Application preferences.

You can grab them here: https://github.com/clintmod/mac-preferences-backup

They're pretty simple. I just loop over the domains from running `defaults domains` and then call `default export [domain] [plist file path]`.

Then to restore I just loop over all the plist files in the dir and run `default import [plist file path]`

You can modify the `config.py` file if you want to backup to a different dir. The default dir is `~/Dropbox/MacPrefsBackup`.

Comment: Interesting. `defaults (ex|im)port` seems to be an undocumented feature (at least in the official `defaults` manpage; it's documented online by other people)

Answer (score 7):

There is no specific way of doing this, but this is how I do it. My setup is redundant but it works the best for me and nothing is ever lost.

> TL;DR: Make sure you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed. Then run the following.

```
brew install mackup
mackup backup
brew install clintmod/formulas/macprefs
macprefs backup
```

But I recommend you read the docs of these two tools

- [Mackup](https://github.com/lra/mackup)
- [MacPerfs](https://github.com/clintmod/macprefs)

Peace! ✌️

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot find an app/applet that does this, you might need to hack it yourself through Terminal. Take Bluetooth Trackpad for example:

Run:

```
defaults read com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad
```

I get:

```
{
    Clicking = 0;
    DragLock = 0;
    Dragging = 0;
    TrackpadCornerSecondaryClick = 0;
    TrackpadFiveFingerPinchGesture = 2;
    TrackpadFourFingerHorizSwipeGesture = 2;
    TrackpadFourFingerPinchGesture = 2;
    TrackpadFourFingerVertSwipeGesture = 2;
    TrackpadHandResting = 1;
    TrackpadHorizScroll = 1;
    TrackpadMomentumScroll = 1;
    TrackpadPinch = 1;
    TrackpadRightClick = 1;
    TrackpadRotate = 1;
    TrackpadScroll = 1;
    TrackpadThreeFingerDrag = 0;
    TrackpadThreeFingerHorizSwipeGesture = 2;
    TrackpadThreeFingerTapGesture = 2;
    TrackpadThreeFingerVertSwipeGesture = 2;
    TrackpadTwoFingerDoubleTapGesture = 1;
    TrackpadTwoFingerFromRightEdgeSwipeGesture = 3;
    USBMouseStopsTrackpad = 0;
    UserPreferences = 1;
    version = 5;
}
```

These are my settings for external trackpad. You get find the same results by opening

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.plist`

but simply copying and pasting the `.plist` file to a new computer doesn't change the settings. You have to use `import` (and `export`) options.

```
defaults export com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad ~/Desktop/Test.plist
```

Move `Test.plist` to the new computer, and:

```
defaults import com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad ~/Desktop/Test.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not exactly an export function. You can find (most) preferences in the library. If you hold alt/option and select "Go To" in the Finder menu bar, you can open the user library. There's a folder named preferences which contains the corresponding files. Named like com.apple.xy.plist, where xy is 'dock' for example.